# How to update $@ into a Makefile variable dependent target rule?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile

I have a Makefile defining a variable dependent target like so:

```
SRCFILES=./src/main.c ./src/file.c
# Get the filenames of all the sources
SRCNAMES=$(notdir $(SRCFILES))

OBJDIR=./obj/
# Replace .c to .o in all source names
OBJNAMES=$(SRCNAMES:.c=.o)
# Add the obj/ repository as prefix
OBJFILES=$(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(OBJNAMES))

NAME=myprog

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJFILES)
    gcc $(OBJFILES) -o $(NAME)

$(OBJDIR)%.o: ./src/%.c
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    gcc -c $< -o $@

# If the make debug rule is called, I want my objects to be build into ./obj/debug/
debug: OBJDIR = ./obj/debug/
debug: all
```

With this Makefile, when I run `make debug` I have the following output:

```
❯ make debug
mkdir -p ./obj/debug/
gcc -c src/main.c -o obj/main.o
mkdir -p ./obj/debug/
gcc -c src/file.c -o obj/file.o
gcc ./obj/debug/main.o ./obj/debug/file.o -o myprog
gcc: error: ./obj/debug/main.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: ./obj/debug/file.o: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:16: myprog] Error 1
```

My problem is into the two first rows of this output:

```
mkdir -p ./obj/debug/  # <----------- Here we see that the $(OBJDIR) variable has been updated

gcc -c src/main.c -o obj/main.o # <-- However, the $@ variable which is generated from $(OBJDIR)%.o hasn't been updated accordingly
```

How can I make the `$@` automatic variable to update when $(OBJDIR) is changed ?

Comment: Your `OBJFILES=$(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(OBJNAMES))` appear to be set set before you update `debug: OBJDIR = ./obj/debug/`. You will need to make sure you have which directory to use set before you fill your `...FILES` variables.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I don't think so, the `OBJFILES` variable is properly updated as you can see line 5: `gcc ./obj/debug/main.o ./obj/debug/file.o -o myprog`

Comment: Yes, but `./obj/debug/main.o ./obj/debug/file.o` do not exist. They were compiled to `cc -c src/main.c -o obj/main.o` above.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, that's my question. `-o $@` should be `./obj/debug/main.o` since it come from `$(OBJDIR)%.o` and `OBJDIR` is redefined by `debug` before the call to `all`. I can't really know in advance if the Makefile will be called with `debug` rule.

Comment: The only way I have handled this in the past is by passing a variable to `make`, e.g. `make with=debug` and then check `ifeq ($(with), debug)` then update the directory locations. Otherwise if `make debug` is supposed to handle that for you automatically -- I'd have to go back to the documentation and figure it out.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes, the variable and condition is what I've also figured out. And yes, I would like it to be automatically handled by `debug` rule. I've digged up into the docs myself and find out some things related to "variables second expansion" who look like what I'm trying to do, but I haven't been able to make it work yet.

Comment: You're using [Target-specific Variable Values](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html), and at the bottom it says `Be aware that a given prerequisite will only be built once per invocation of make, at most`. I think that's what's your problem here. A recursive make would work: `debug: ; $(MAKE) OBJDIR=./obj/debug/ all`

Comment: Presuming that you will change the compile or link commands for the debug-version of the object files or executable: Why don't you name these files differently and save yourself from trouble? Make works best with a static dependency tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `make` parses a Makefile it will expand all the variables upon building a dependency tree for targets that are not implicit targets. So when you call `make debug` it tries to build `myprog`, which in turn tries to build `obj/main.o`, not `obj/debug/main.o`, since the `$(OBJFILES)` has already been expanded when the rule for `myprog` was parsed. That's why `$@` expands to `obj/main.o` even though the variable is correct. See for yourself:

```
$ make -dr debug
...
Considering target file 'debug'.
 File 'debug' does not exist.
 Looking for an implicit rule for 'debug'.
 No implicit rule found for 'debug'.
  Considering target file 'all'.
   File 'all' does not exist.
   Looking for an implicit rule for 'all'.
   No implicit rule found for 'all'.
    Considering target file 'myprog'.
     File 'myprog' does not exist.
      Considering target file 'obj/main.o'.
       File 'obj/main.o' does not exist.
       Looking for an implicit rule for 'obj/main.o'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'main'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite 'src/main.c'.
       Found an implicit rule for 'obj/main.o'.
        Considering target file 'src/main.c'.
         Looking for an implicit rule for 'src/main.c'.
         No implicit rule found for 'src/main.c'.
         Finished prerequisites of target file 'src/main.c'.
        No need to remake target 'src/main.c'.
       Finished prerequisites of target file 'obj/main.o'.
      Must remake target 'obj/main.o'.
mkdir -p ./obj/debug/
...
```

It is possible to make it work though. First of all, you would need to use second expansion to resolve dependencies at execution time. Second, you would need to make your `$(NAME)` target an implicit rule somehow to let `make` reevaluate the expression. Last, since your object location will differ (include `debug` or not), it will also propagate to the source location, which should generally be the same. I was able to make it work like this:

```
$ cat Makefile
SRCFILES=./src/main.c ./src/file.c
# Get the filenames of all the sources
SRCNAMES=$(notdir $(SRCFILES))

OBJDIR=./obj/
# Replace .c to .o in all source names
OBJNAMES=$(SRCNAMES:.c=.o)
# Add the obj/ repository as prefix
OBJFILES=$(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(OBJNAMES))

NAME=myprog

.SECONDEXPANSION:

all: $(CURDIR)/$(NAME)

# Implicit rule due to %
%/$(NAME): $$(OBJFILES)
        gcc $(OBJFILES) -o $(NAME)

%.o: ./src/$$(notdir $$*).c
        mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
        gcc -c $< -o $@

# If the make debug rule is called, I want my objects to be build into ./obj/debug/
debug: OBJDIR = ./obj/debug/
debug: all
```

Output:

```
$ make
mkdir -p ./obj/
gcc -c src/main.c -o obj/main.o
mkdir -p ./obj/
gcc -c src/file.c -o obj/file.o
gcc ./obj/main.o ./obj/file.o -o myprog
rm obj/main.o obj/file.o

$ rm -rf obj myprog
$ make debug
mkdir -p ./obj/debug/
gcc -c src/main.c -o obj/debug/main.o
mkdir -p ./obj/debug/
gcc -c src/file.c -o obj/debug/file.o
gcc ./obj/debug/main.o ./obj/debug/file.o -o myprog
rm obj/debug/main.o obj/debug/file.o
```

Personally I would also consider building final binaries with different name or location, otherwise you will never be sure what has been built.